# Time-out w/ Gradle deploy of Spring-based web application to WAS Liberty

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, websphere-liberty

I am trying to write a simple Spring-based web service to run on WAS Liberty 8.5.5.9.  The application is a Gradle project, and I build and deploy the application with the command `gradle clean build deploy`.  However, this fails with the following message:

```
[ant:deploy] CWWKM2006I: Deploying application .../userSetting.war to the dropins folder.
[ant:deploy] CWWKM2010I: Searching for CWWKZ0001I.*userSetting in 
             /home/lavin/WASLiberty/usr/servers/defaultServer/logs/messages.log.
             This search will timeout after 30 seconds.
[ant:deploy] CWWKM2011E: Timed out searching for CWWKZ0001I.*userSetting in
             /home/lavin/WASLiberty/usr/servers/defaultServer/logs/messages.log.
:deploy FAILED
```

I *do* see userSetting.war in the `dropins/` folder, but I run into problems trying to start the application, so I assume the deployment is broken.

Can someone please explain what the problem is and how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

The tooling here is waiting for up to 30 seconds to see the `CWWKZ0001I` message, which is the "application XYZ started" message ID.  Since the build script did not find this message in 30 seconds, there are 2 possibilities:

1. The application failed to start (probably the case)
2. The application is taking longer than 30s to start (probably not the case, unless your .war application is massive)

I'll assume that the application simply failed to start, in which case you will want to check the server logs to figure out *why* the application failed to start. As the console indicates, the message.log can be found at `/home/lavin/WASLiberty/usr/servers/defaultServer/logs/messages.log`

---

On a side-note, Liberty 8.5.5.9 is rather old, and the Liberty team has made specific efforts to better support Spring applications since then. In particular, check out this blog post:
 
[Open Liberty Spring Boot Starter](https://openliberty.io/news/2017/11/29/liberty-spring-boot.html)

In case you haven't heard of OpenLiberty before, its an open-source **subset** of WAS Liberty (meaning anything that works on OpenLiberty will work on WAS Liberty).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  I checked, and *nothing* is getting written to `messages.log` or `console.log`.   Dumb question:   Do I have to start the server before deploying?

Comment: Ah, yep that would imply the server is not being started.  If you are using the `liberty` gradle plugin, it has tasks that will automatically manage the server lifecycle though.  You can check it out here: https://github.com/WASdev/ci.gradle